# Redis optimal hash set entry size

Tags: memory, optimization, hash, redis

I have some questions regarding the optimal entry size setting for Redis hash sets.

1. In this example [memory-optimization](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) they use 100 hash entries
   per key but use hash-max-zipmap-entries 256 ?  Why not
   hash-max-zipmap-entries 100 or 128?
2. On the redis website (above link) they used max hash entry size of
   100, but in this post [instagram](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs), they mention 1000 entries. So
   does this mean the optimal setting is a function of the product of
   hash-max-zipmap-entries & hash-max-zipmap-value ?(ie in this case
   Instagram has smaller hash-values than memory optimization example?)

Your comments/clarifications are much appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/9qM9iSeRAA4

Answer (score 1):

The key is, [from here](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/9-1-3-performance-issues-for-long-ziplists-and-intsets/):

> manipulating the compact versions of these [ziplist] structures can become slow as they grow longer

and

> [as ziplists grow longer] fetching/updating individual fields of a HASH, Redis will have to decode many individual entries, and CPU caches won’t be as effective

So to your questions

1. This page just shows an example and I doubt the author gave much thought to the exact values. In real life, IF you wanted to take advantage of ziplists, and you knew your number of entries per hash was <100, then setting it at 100, 128 or 256 would make no difference. `hash-max-zipmap-entries` is only the LIMIT over which you're telling Redis to change the encoding from ziplist to hash.
2. There may be some truth in your "product of hash-max-zipmap-entries & hash-max-zipmap-value" idea, but I'm speculating. More importantly, first you have to define "optimal" based on what you want to do.  If you want to do lots of HSET/HGETs in a large ziplist, it will be slower than if you used a hash.  But if you never get/update single fields only ever do HMSET/HGETALL on a key, large ziplists wouldn't slow you down. The Instagram 1000 was THEIR optimal number based on THEIR specific data, use cases, and Redis function call frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

You encouraged me to read both links and it seems that you are asking for "default value for hash table size".

I don't think that it's possible to say that one number is universal for all possibilities. The described mechanism is similar to standard hash mapping. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

If you have small size of hash-table, it means that many various hash values point into the same array, where the *equals* method is used to find out the item.

On the other hand, large hash table means that it allocates large memory along with many empty fields. But this scales well as the algorithm uses O(1) big O notation and there is no *equals* searching for the item.

In general the size of the table IMHO depends on the overall count of all elements you expect to put into the table and it also depends on the diversity of the key. I mean if every hash start with "0001" not even size=100000 would help you.